# incremental counter to a dataframe based on unique values from a column

Tags: pandas

Existing Dataframe :

```
Unique_Id          sms_sent_date         
A                    11-01-2022                   
A                    11-01-2022                   
A                    12-01-2022                   
A                    13-01-2022                   

B                    02-02-2022                   
B                    03-02-2022                   
B                    06-02-2022                   
B                    06-02-2022
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
Unique_Id          sms_sent_date         unique_sms_counter
A                    11-01-2022                   1
A                    11-01-2022                   1
A                    12-01-2022                   2
A                    13-01-2022                   3

B                    02-02-2022                   1
B                    03-02-2022                   2
B                    06-02-2022                   3
B                    06-02-2022                   3
```

I trying to add the smsq_counter which shall count the unique sms sent to a unique Id.
tried this `df.groupby(['Unique_Id','sms_sent_date']).cumcount()` but stuck with applying it on entire dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['unique_sms_counter'] = (
  # get non duplicates
 (~df.duplicated(['Unique_Id', 'sms_sent_date']))
  # increment per group
 .groupby(df['Unique_Id']).cumsum()
)
```

output:

```
  Unique_Id sms_sent_date  unique_sms_counter
0         A    11-01-2022                   1
1         A    11-01-2022                   1
2         A    12-01-2022                   2
3         A    13-01-2022                   3
4         B    02-02-2022                   1
5         B    03-02-2022                   2
6         B    06-02-2022                   3
7         B    06-02-2022                   3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `factorize` on groupby:

```
df['unique_sms_counter'] = df.groupby(['Unique_Id'])['sms_sent_date'].transform(lambda x: x.factorize()[0]+1)
```

Or, if your date is actual datetime type, you can use `rank`:

```
df['sms_sent_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sms_sent_date'], dayfirst=True)

df.groupby('Unique_Id')['sms_sent_date'].rank('dense').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
  Unique_Id sms_sent_date  unique_sms_counter
0         A    11-01-2022                   1
1         A    11-01-2022                   1
2         A    12-01-2022                   2
3         A    13-01-2022                   3
4         B    02-02-2022                   1
5         B    03-02-2022                   2
6         B    06-02-2022                   3
7         B    06-02-2022                   3
```